# Were the Puritans for a State Church?

Tags: united-states, religion, 17th-century, founding-fathers

In a book titled *America's Providential History* it states on page 84 that

> The major Puritan weakness was their holding to the idea of a State
>   Church. They saw nothing wrong with a National church.

But it doesn't give any evidence.  I personally don't think that they would want a State Church, since they knew that England's church had started out good and eventually became rotten (in their minds).  Is there any evidence out there that supports this idea?

Comment: Note that the opposing a *specific* state church doesn't necessarily mean opposition to *the idea of* a state church.

Comment: The Puritans were definitely in favor of their colony being officially Puritan.  I'll see if I can dig up some references.

Comment: @Joe - I was looking for the same references. The Wikipedia page on [Separation of church and state in the United States](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_church_and_state_in_the_United_States) has a table showing when the official state supported churches in all the colonies were disestablished, but unfortunately the article is horribly cited.

Comment: @Comintern So is there no visible evidence (at least from web sources)?

Comment: Several colonies had an official religion. I believe Maryland was officially Catholic.  Pennsylvania was an early exception, most likely because there were already a few religions resident in the early settlements so state toleration made sense.

Comment: When first starting out, Puritans and other colonists never really saw themselves as starting a continent spanning entity. They wanted their little corner of the new world to be run by themselves in their own way, because they had been shafted whenever someone else was in charge.  By the time these questions came up for the US as a whole, the situation had changed and thus their feelings probably changed with it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, Puritans supported a state church.

- Ministers' salaries were [paid by taxes levied on all residents of the colonies](http://nationalhumanitiescenter.org/tserve/eighteen/ekeyinfo/chustate.htm).
  Colonial [meetinghouses](http://www.colonialmeetinghouses.com/background_information.shtml), also built at the taxpayers' expense, were used for both town business and religious worship.
- Participation in political life was dependent on one's religious background, as [voting rights were restricted to members of the church](http://public.wsu.edu/~campbelld/amlit/purdef.htm). Note that "church membership" is even stricter than being a Puritan: one had to be a member of the "elect" who could testify to their personal experience of God.
- Dissenters such as [Quakers were banished from Puritan colonies](http://nvdatabase.swarthmore.edu/content/quakers-fight-religious-freedom-puritan-massachusetts-1656-1661) and on occasion executed.

A good source generally on Puritan culture is David Hackett Fischer's [Albion's Seed](https://books.google.com/books?id=_gd63RFlXIMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=albion%27s%20seed&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bn66VK0V7MixBMS1guAO&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=albion's%20seed&f=false). Bernard Bailyn's [Ideological Origins of the American Revolution](https://books.google.com/books?id=p6-tKuFD1KsC&printsec=frontcover&dq=ideological%20origins%20of%20the%20american%20revolution&hl=en&sa=X&ei=hH66VNOwC_eHsQTcxoCoBQ&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=ideological%20origins%20of%20the%20american%20revolution&f=false) has a brief but good discussion of the development of disestablishment sentiment in the years before the Revolution.